# Error sending NSURL * to parameter of type NSString * using initWithContentsOfFile:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, runtime-error

I am getting the error

> "Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSURL *' to parameter of type 'NSString *'

when calling `initWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:`

```
- (NSMutableArray *)qBlock{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://addressToPath.php"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSStringEncoding encoding;
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:url 
                                                     usedEncoding:&encoding 
                                                            error:&error];
    const char *convert = [response UTF8String];
    NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:convert];
    NSMutableArray *sample = [responseString JSONValue];


    return sample;

}
```

Comment: ...and what did you do to try to fix this yourself?

Comment: I was changing from initWithContentsOfURL to initWithContentOfURL:encode:error. So the above was what i did...

Answer (score 3):

`initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` receives a `NSString *` as file path, not `NSURL *`. You need to call `initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:`:

```
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url 
                                             usedEncoding:&encoding 
                                                    error:&error];
```

Comment: Thanx mate... i totally overlooked that part

Comment: initWithContentsOfURL was first deprecated in 2.0...?